# IFrame modal, mobile keyboard obscures typing fields upon selecting text input

Tags: css, iframe, mobile

On mobile web browser when keyboard springs up it covers up the input fields on this iFrame. Normally content is pushed up but this Iframe is absolutely positioned to cover the whole screen with transparent background.  http://learntoad.com/

Answer (score 1):

using position:fixed instead of absolute allowed me to create a screen overlay iFrame, I did have to use an event listener messenger to adjust the ZIndex during the time the overlay was displayed and adjust it back after close.